# Customizing bootstrap - how to change the number of columns under a certain width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm starting to customize my bootstrap and so far I have something very similar to the following template:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

but instead of having three span4s, I have four span3s.  Once the browser reaches a certain width, I'd like to have three span3s.  Then, at another width, two span3s.

Is there any way to do this with straight css?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply reduce the width of `.span3`s to be that of `.span2`'s within the media query.

```
/* Bootstrap defaults: */
.span3 {
    width:270px;
}

.span4 {
    width:370px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 767px) {
    /* Decreased span4 size within media query. */
    .span4 {
        width:270px;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I misworded my question.  Just updated for clarity.

Comment: Well the same still applies, to an extent. I've updated my answer slightly. You may want to have a look at Bootstrap's [responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) section.

Comment: Thanks James.  I see how to change the width of the four span3s I have, but how about only displaying three or two span3s in a row, instead of four?  I can't find anything like that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using jQuery / javascript. ".colElement" is each .span* element you want to affect. Just adjust the window width breakpoints to suite your needs.

Based on twitter bootstrap 2.*

```
function arrangeColumns(tile, numColsLG, numColsMED, numColsSM){
    $(tile).removeClass('first');
    var colSize = 0;
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    switch(numColsLG) {
        case 2: colSizeLG = 6; break;
        case 3: colSizeLG = 4; break;
        case 4: colSizeLG = 3; break;
        case 5: colSizeLG = 3; break;
        case 6: colSizeLG = 2; break;
    }
    switch(numColsMED) {
        case 2: colSizeMED = 6; break;
        case 3: colSizeMED = 4; break;
        case 4: colSizeMED = 3; break;
        case 5: colSizeMED = 3; break;
        case 6: colSizeMED = 2; break;
    }
    switch(numColsSM) {
        case 2: colSizeSM = 6; break;
        case 3: colSizeSM = 4; break;
        case 4: colSizeSM = 3; break;
        case 5: colSizeSM = 3; break;
        case 6: colSizeSM = 2; break;
    }

    if( windowWidth > 1200){
        $(tile).removeClass('span' + colSizeMED + " " + 'span' + colSizeSM);
        $(tile).addClass('span' + colSizeLG);
        $(tile + ':nth-child('+numColsLG+'n+1)').addClass('first');     
    } else if( windowWidth < 1200 && windowWidth > 900) {
        $(tile).removeClass('span' + colSizeLG + " " + 'span' + colSizeSM);
        $(tile).addClass('span' + colSizeMED);
        $(tile + ':nth-child('+numColsMED+'n+1)').addClass('first');        
    } else {
        $(tile).removeClass('span' + colSizeLG + " " + 'span' + colSizeMED);
        $(tile).addClass('span' + colSizeSM);
        $(tile + ':nth-child('+numColsSM+'n+1)').addClass('first');     
    }
}       


/* Initialize */
arrangeColumns('.colElement', 3, 2, 2);
/* Call on window resize  */
$(window).resize(function() {
    arrangeColumns('.colElement', 3, 2, 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this for my prototype. I can think of three dirty solutions, none of them really perfect and enough for me to implement in production code. However all of them work fine if you need it for simple static website or to demo something using prototype.

1. Code up two scenarios. One with 4 columns and another with 3 columns. Hide/show needed one with @media queries. (use utility classes from bootstrap).
2. Similar to no. 1 but less messy. Rather than having two different scenarios coded up - dynamically change HTML markup. Put a simple JS/Jquery script which will remove some classes and add new ones on certain width. You may need to destroy some [div class="row"] and create new ones on the fly to achieve different number of item in a row.
3. Ignore grid for this section (if you can) and hard-code your items. You can fix their widths so when not enough space they will start breaking into new line or just use percentages and hard-code specific widths with @media queries. You can always use all columns and put your hard-coded items inside a row (e.g. using all 12 columns as container).
4. Bonus - use Isotope (http://mpezzi.github.io/bootstrap_isotope/) or Mansonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ to achieve your effect.

It would be sooo nice to have a control over how many items in a row at specific breakpoint I would like to display but this would require rethinking bootstrap... Maybe they will figure it out and add as an add-on or something... At the moment I can't even think how this could work with bootstrap default classes...

Answer (score 0):

I understand you asked for Bootsrap but Zurb Foundation has a functionality like this built-in

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-4 medium-6 large-12 columns">
  </div>
  <div class="small-8 medium-6 columns">
  </div>
</div>
```

What that will do is create 2 columns of 4 and 8 for small devices or 2 columns of 6 for medium devices and 1 fullwidth column of 12 on large screens. If you want to keep the same layout across screen sizes just small-* columns and it will use for medium and large media queries